# Jackson json @JsonIgnore to work with extended classes?

Tags: json, jackson

I'm using this @JsonIgnoreProperties to exclude properties from serialization but this doesn't work on extended classes, is there a way to force it to exclude properties on on extended classes, that should be all classes that extend this one with @JsonIgnoreProperties does not exclude properties from superclass?

Answer (score 0):

if @JsonIgnore annotation is used for each field it works with subclasses @JsonIgnoreProperties doesn't (at least in jackson 1.9.13)